# Update Postgresql table straight from a JSON object

Tags: json, postgresql

I use

```
select to_json(host) from host where id=3
```

to query data from my postgreSQL database the result is like:

```
{"id":3,"project_id":1,"name":"a","mac":"abc","info":"x"}
```

after altering the data in my application I want to update the table.

Is there a "json"-way to do this? Not doing a ordinary update like

```
update host set project_id=1, name='a', mac='abc',info='x' where id=1;
```

Comment: You are looking for the `update` statement.

Comment: sure, but I want to know if there is a way to use the json directly in the `update` statement

Comment: Yes, that's possible. But without more details this is impossible to answer. Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: There is no way you can avoid the `set column = value` syntax. `UPDATE` simply doesn't support that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`jsonb_populate_record`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE) in the [`update from` clause](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-update.html)

```
update host
set
    (project_id, name, mac, info) =
    (j.project_id, j.name, j.mac, j.info)
from jsonb_populate_record ( null::host,
    '{"id":1,"project_id":1,"name":"a","mac":"abc","info":"x"}'::jsonb
) j
where host.id = j.id
```

Comment: Just wondering why `jsonb_populate_record` over `json_populate_record`? Also, can either json update function somehow ignore a null field in the JSON, i.e. don't update if JSON is null?

Comment: A little late to the party, but in case someone else needs to remove null fields, check out `jsonb_strip_nulls` https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html